# How to write async data with Hiredis

Tags: asynchronous, redis

I'm struggling with Hiredis asynchronous API. I just want to write some key value pairs into Redis without waiting the reply. I dont need that, i'm not interesting that it was successfull or not. I just want to send SET commands in nonblocking mode.
I tried to use the async API of Redis but did not manage to get it work as I want.
Is it possible to use redisAsyncCommand(ctx, 0, 0, ) without event loop? Do I need to create a thread for this operation? But then what means async?

Thanks!

Comment: You could supply a callback that simply ignores the reply, no?

Comment: It is possible to call redisAsyncCommand without specifying callback function, ex: redisAsyncCommand(ctx, 0, 0, "SET k1 1"); The problem is that just calling this function the command is not sent to the redis server, at least I cant see the key in the redis until I create an event loop. But that will bolck the thread.